# anchor inline text with image

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, openxml

i am trying to add a image with the option inline with text, i already am able to place floating images around text, but i want to give the option to put them inline with text, as i read the docs it says that i can't use the wrap mode for the inline option.

My daubt is how can i set the anchor element to inline without changing all my function?

**at the moment i have this:**

```
 private static Drawing DrawingManager(string relationshipId, string name, int cxVal, int cyVal, string impPosition, String horizontalAlign, double? horizontalPosition, double? verticalPosition, String wrapMode)
        {
            int iWidth = 0;
            int iHeight = 0;

            iWidth = (int)Math.Round((decimal)cxVal * EMUTOPIXELCONVERTVALUE);
            iHeight = (int)Math.Round((decimal)cyVal * EMUTOPIXELCONVERTVALUE);

            // Define the reference of the image.
            DW.Anchor anchor = new DW.Anchor();


            string haPosition = impPosition;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(haPosition))
            {
                haPosition = horizontalAlign;
            }

            DW.VerticalPosition vp = new DW.VerticalPosition(new DW.PositionOffset("0"))
            {
                RelativeFrom =
                    DW.VerticalRelativePositionValues.Paragraph
            };

            DW.PositionOffset positionOffset2 = new DW.PositionOffset();
            positionOffset2.Text = MathOpenXml.centimetersToEMU(verticalPosition).ToString();

            if (verticalPosition != null)
            {
                vp = new DW.VerticalPosition(positionOffset2)
                {
                    RelativeFrom = DW.VerticalRelativePositionValues.Paragraph

                };
            }

            DW.HorizontalPosition hp = new DW.HorizontalPosition(new DW.HorizontalAlignment(haPosition))
            {
                RelativeFrom =
                      DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Column
            };

            if (horizontalPosition != null)
            {
                DW.PositionOffset positionOffsetConv = new DW.PositionOffset(MathOpenXml.centimetersToEMU(horizontalPosition).ToString());
                hp = new DW.HorizontalPosition(new DW.PositionOffset(MathOpenXml.centimetersToEMU(horizontalPosition).ToString()))
                {
                    RelativeFrom =
                      DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Column
                };
            }

            // how the text displays with the image


            anchor.Append(new DW.SimplePosition() { X = 0L, Y = 0L });
            anchor.Append(hp);
            anchor.Append(vp);
            anchor.Append(
                new DW.Extent()
                {
                    Cx = iWidth,
                    Cy = iHeight
                }
            );
            anchor.Append(
                new DW.EffectExtent()
                {
                    LeftEdge = 0L,
                    TopEdge = 0L,
                    RightEdge = 0L,
                    BottomEdge = 0L
                }
            );

            if (wrapMode != "In Line With Text")
            {
                anchor = wrapText(anchor, wrapMode);
            }
            anchor.Append(
                new DW.DocProperties()
                {
                    Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                    Name = name
                }
            );
            anchor.Append(
                new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                      new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true })
            );
            anchor.Append(
                new A.Graphic(
                      new A.GraphicData(
                        new PIC.Picture(

                          new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                            new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                            {
                                Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                Name = name + ".jpg"
                            },
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),

                            new PIC.BlipFill(
                                new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension()
                                        {
                                            Uri =
                                            "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                        })
                                )
                                {
                                    Embed = relationshipId,
                                    CompressionState =
                                    A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                new A.Stretch(
                                    new A.FillRectangle())),

                          new PIC.ShapeProperties(

                            new A.Transform2D(
                              new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },

                              new A.Extents()
                              {
                                  Cx = iWidth,
                                  Cy = iHeight
                              }),

                            new A.PresetGeometry(
                              new A.AdjustValueList()
                            )
                            { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }
                          )
                        )
                  )
                      { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
            );

            anchor.DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U;
            anchor.DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U;
            anchor.DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)114300U;
            anchor.DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)114300U;
            anchor.SimplePos = false;
            anchor.RelativeHeight = (UInt32Value)251658240U;
            anchor.BehindDoc = true;
            anchor.Locked = false;
            anchor.LayoutInCell = true;
            anchor.AllowOverlap = true;


            Drawing element = new Drawing();
            element.Append(anchor);
            return element;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks how image wraps the text besides
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dw">drawing element(pic)</param>
        /// <param name="wrapMode">user choice, how he wants to wrap the image</param>
        public static DW.Anchor wrapText(DW.Anchor anchor, String wrapMode)
        {
            switch (wrapMode)
            {
                case "Square":
                    DW.WrapSquare wrapSquare = new DW.WrapSquare() { WrapText = DW.WrapTextValues.BothSides };
                    anchor.Append(wrapSquare);
                    break;
                case "Tight":
                    DW.WrapTight tight = new DW.WrapTight() { WrapText = DW.WrapTextValues.BothSides };
                    anchor.Append(tight);
                    break;
                case "Through":
                    DW.WrapThrough wrapThrough = new DW.WrapThrough() { WrapText = DW.WrapTextValues.BothSides };
                    anchor.Append(wrapThrough);
                    break;
                case "Top and bottom":
                    DW.WrapTopBottom wrapTopAndBottom = new DW.WrapTopBottom();
                    anchor.Append(wrapTopAndBottom);
                    break;
                case "Behind Text":
                    DW.WrapNone behindText = new DW.WrapNone(); //behind doc must be true
                    anchor.Append(behindText);
                    break;
                case "In Front Text":
                    DW.WrapNone frontText = new DW.WrapNone(); //Fron doc must be false
                    anchor.Append(frontText);
                    break;
                default:
                    anchor.Append(new DW.WrapSquare() { WrapText = DW.WrapTextValues.BothSides });
                    break;
            }
            return anchor;
        }
```

i already used the openxml productivity sdk but it is not specific about how i can do this, any help?

Comment: Can you pinpoint your code a bit?

Comment: the first part is all about the image creating i extract the code from the openxml developing tool, it edits the image bahviour, the seconf function is responsable for the image wrapping, my problem is that the anchor can be inline or floating and in this case it should be inline but i can't set it up