# How to add ''anchor'' images in open-xml wordprocessing document?

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am currently trying to add images to a wordprocessing document using open-**xml sdk 2.5**.
This works out fine for me with inline images, but I never managed to get anchor images working.

For clarification: With inline images, I mean adding an inline object to a drawing object, with anchor images, adding anchor object to drawing object.

I already read the docs.microsoft documentation about adding images to a wordprocessing document, but this only handles inline images (Link: [Insert a picture into a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document). I further found a stack overflow answer, which provides a sample implementation from an anchor object, the problem is this sample does not work (Link to sample code: [anchor inline text with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814121/anchor-inline-text-with-image).
I further made a word document with an anchor image and opened this Wordfile in the Microsoft productivity tool. Then I tried to copy-paste the generated image code to my project, which also didn't work out. I also tried to tweak this code, but it didn't work either.

I provide here my inline and anchor code, together with the resulting xml files.
I get the relationshipId as mentioned in the microsoft docs:

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = (MainDocumentPart)targetDocPart;
                        imgp = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
                        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
                        imgp.FeedData(memStream);
                        string relationshipId = targetDocPart.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
WordDrawing = GenerateInlineDrawing(relationshipId);
//Later this drawing is added to a run, paragraph and finally to the doc...
```

**Inline Code:**

```
        private Drawing GenerateInlineDrawing(string relationshipId)
        {
            DW.Extent extent = new DW.Extent() {Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L};
            DW.EffectExtent effectEx = new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
                LeftEdge = 500L,
                TopEdge = 0L,
                RightEdge = 0L,
                BottomEdge = 0L
            };
            DW.DocProperties docProp = new DW.DocProperties()
            {
                Id = (UInt32Value) 1U,
                Name = "Picture 1"
            };
            DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVis = new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new A.GraphicFrameLocks() {NoChangeAspect = true});
            A.Graphic graphic = new A.Graphic(
                new A.GraphicData(
                        new PIC.Picture(
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                {
                                    Id = (UInt32Value) 0U,
                                    Name = "New Bitmap Image.png"
                                },
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new PIC.BlipFill(
                                new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension()
                                        {
                                            Uri =
                                                "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                        })
                                )
                                {
                                    Embed = relationshipId,
                                    CompressionState =
                                        A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                new A.Stretch(
                                    new A.FillRectangle())),
                            new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                new A.Transform2D(
                                    new A.Offset() {X = 0L, Y = 0L},
                                    new A.Extents() {Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L}),
                                new A.PresetGeometry(
                                        new A.AdjustValueList()
                                    )
                                    {Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle}))
                    )
                    {Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"});
            //nonVis, effectEx
            return new Drawing(new DW.Inline(extent, docProp, graphic));
        }
```

Inline XML:

```
<w:document xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0E1A9AD6">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:drawing>
          <wp:inline>
            <wp:extent cx="990000" cy="792000" />
            <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" />
            <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="New Bitmap Image.png" />
                    <pic:cNvPicPr />
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="R9428c323687947d3" cstate="print">
                      <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" />
                      </a:extLst>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:stretch>
                      <a:fillRect />
                    </a:stretch>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                      <a:ext cx="990000" cy="792000" />
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst />
                    </a:prstGeom>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="01834FB7">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidRPr="00A36CD5" w:rsidR="00A178D9" w:rsidSect="00DC0279">
      <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId7" />
      <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId8" />
      <w:pgSz w:w="11907" w:h="16840" w:code="9" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1077" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="851" w:footer="851" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**Anchor Code:**

```
 private Drawing GenerateAnchorDrawing(string relationshipId)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

            DW.Extent extent = new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L };
            DW.EffectExtent effectEx = new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
                LeftEdge = 500L,
                TopEdge = 0L,
                RightEdge = 0L,
                BottomEdge = 0L
            };
            DW.DocProperties docProp = new DW.DocProperties()
            {
                Id = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)randomNumber),
                Name = $"Picture {randomNumber+10}"
            };
            DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVis = new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true });
            A.Graphic graphic = new A.Graphic(
                new A.GraphicData(
                        new PIC.Picture(
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                {
                                    Id = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)randomNumber),
                                    Name = $"NewBitmap{randomNumber+10}.png"
                                },
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new PIC.BlipFill(
                                new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension()
                                        {
                                            Uri =
                                                "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                        })
                                )
                                {
                                    Embed = relationshipId,
                                    CompressionState =
                                        A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                new A.Stretch(
                                    new A.FillRectangle())),
                            new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                new A.Transform2D(
                                    new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                    new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                new A.PresetGeometry(
                                        new A.AdjustValueList()
                                    )
                                { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                    )
                { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" });
            DW.SimplePosition simplePos = new SimplePosition(){X = 0,Y=0};
            DW.HorizontalPosition positionH = new DW.HorizontalPosition(new PositionOffset("2084375"));
            positionH.RelativeFrom = HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Column;

            DW.VerticalPosition positionY = new DW.VerticalPosition(new PositionOffset("628878"));
            positionY.RelativeFrom = VerticalRelativePositionValues.Paragraph;

            DW.Anchor anchor = new DW.Anchor(simplePos,positionH,positionY,extent,docProp,graphic);
            anchor.DistanceFromTop = 0;
            anchor.DistanceFromBottom = 0;
            anchor.DistanceFromLeft = 114300;
            anchor.DistanceFromRight = 114300;
            anchor.SimplePosition = simplePos;
            anchor.RelativeHeight = 251658240;
            anchor.BehindDoc = true;
            anchor.Locked = false;
            anchor.LayoutInCell = true;
            anchor.AllowOverlap = true;
            anchor.EditId = "7CEAA868";
            anchor.AnchorId = GetRandomHexNumber(8);


            //nonVis, effectEx
            return new Drawing(anchor);
}

static Random random = new Random();
        public static string GetRandomHexNumber(int digits)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[digits / 2];
            random.NextBytes(buffer);
            string result = String.Concat(buffer.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
            if (digits % 2 == 0)
                return result;
            return result + random.Next(16).ToString("X");
        }
```

Anchor XML:

```
<w:document xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0E1A9AD6">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:drawing>
          <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="1" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:editId="7CEAA868" wp14:anchorId="2AC6C3E0">
            <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0" />
            <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
              <wp:posOffset>2084375</wp:posOffset>
            </wp:positionH>
            <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
              <wp:posOffset>628878</wp:posOffset>
            </wp:positionV>
            <wp:extent cx="990000" cy="792000" />
            <wp:docPr id="71" name="Picture 81" />
            <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="71" name="NewBitmap81.png" />
                    <pic:cNvPicPr />
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="Rd17f79509d4844d0" cstate="print">
                      <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" />
                      </a:extLst>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:stretch>
                      <a:fillRect />
                    </a:stretch>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                      <a:ext cx="990000" cy="792000" />
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst />
                    </a:prstGeom>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:anchor>
        </w:drawing>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="01834FB7">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="de-DE" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidRPr="00A36CD5" w:rsidR="00A178D9" w:rsidSect="00DC0279">
      <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId7" />
      <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId8" />
      <w:pgSz w:w="11907" w:h="16840" w:code="9" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1077" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="851" w:footer="851" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

When I execute the anchor code and try to open the resulting document, I get the following error:
''We're sorry. We can't open Document_ReportWithImages.docx because we found a problem with its contets.

Details. No error detail available
Location: Part:/word/document.xml, Line: 0, Column: 0

Screenshot:

[image]

So question is, how to get these anchor images into a word file :-)

Comment: Have you tried creating a very simple document in the Word UI (contains maybe a few characters and one SHAPE (floating image))? Then open it in the OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool and take a look at the code that generates for creating the document.

Comment: Yeah, actually I tried it, but I forgot to mention it in my initial answer.
It didn't work either. I copy-pasted the generated code, made some small adjustments,  but nothing worked :/

I will add this tried solution now.
Thanks for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following function. I have managed to insert an Anchor Image in a paragraph at left using following function.

```
using Wp = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DWp = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using OXML = DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

 public static Wp.Drawing GetAnchorPicture(String imagePartId)
            {
                Wp.Drawing _drawing = new Wp.Drawing();
                DWp.Anchor _anchor = new DWp.Anchor()
                {
                    DistanceFromTop = (OXML.UInt32Value)0U,
                    DistanceFromBottom = (OXML.UInt32Value)0U,
                    DistanceFromLeft = (OXML.UInt32Value)0U,
                    DistanceFromRight = (OXML.UInt32Value)0U,
                    SimplePos = false,
                    RelativeHeight = (OXML.UInt32Value)0U,
                    BehindDoc = true,
                    Locked = false,
                    LayoutInCell = true,
                    AllowOverlap = true,
                    EditId = "44CEF5E4",
                    AnchorId = "44803ED1"
                };
                DWp.SimplePosition _spos = new DWp.SimplePosition()
                {
                    X = 0L,
                    Y = 0L
                };

                DWp.HorizontalPosition _hp = new DWp.HorizontalPosition()
                {
                    RelativeFrom = DWp.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Column
                };
                DWp.PositionOffset _hPO = new DWp.PositionOffset();
                _hPO.Text = "76200";
                _hp.Append(_hPO);

                DWp.VerticalPosition _vp = new DWp.VerticalPosition()
                {
                    RelativeFrom = DWp.VerticalRelativePositionValues.Paragraph
                };
                DWp.PositionOffset _vPO = new DWp.PositionOffset();
                _vPO.Text = "83820";
                _vp.Append(_vPO);

                DWp.Extent _e = new DWp.Extent()
                {
                    Cx = 989965L,
                    Cy = 791845L
                };

                DWp.EffectExtent _ee = new DWp.EffectExtent()
                {
                    LeftEdge = 0L,
                    TopEdge = 0L,
                    RightEdge = 0L,
                    BottomEdge = 0L
                };

                DWp.WrapTight _wp = new DWp.WrapTight()
                {
                    WrapText = DWp.WrapTextValues.BothSides
                };

                DWp.WrapPolygon _wpp = new DWp.WrapPolygon()
                {
                    Edited = false
                };
                DWp.StartPoint _sp = new DWp.StartPoint()
                {
                    X = 0L,
                    Y = 0L
                };

                DWp.LineTo _l1 = new DWp.LineTo() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
                DWp.LineTo _l2 = new DWp.LineTo() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
                DWp.LineTo _l3 = new DWp.LineTo() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
                DWp.LineTo _l4 = new DWp.LineTo() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };

                _wpp.Append(_sp);
                _wpp.Append(_l1);
                _wpp.Append(_l2);
                _wpp.Append(_l3);
                _wpp.Append(_l4);

                _wp.Append(_wpp);

                DWp.DocProperties _dp = new DWp.DocProperties()
                {
                    Id = 1U,
                    Name = "Test Picture"
                };

                OXML.Drawing.Graphic _g = new OXML.Drawing.Graphic();
                OXML.Drawing.GraphicData _gd = new OXML.Drawing.GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" };
                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.Picture _pic = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.Picture();

                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties _nvpp = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties();
                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties _nvdp = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Picture"
                };
                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties _nvpdp = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
                _nvpp.Append(_nvdp);
                _nvpp.Append(_nvpdp);


                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.BlipFill _bf = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.BlipFill();
                OXML.Drawing.Blip _b = new OXML.Drawing.Blip()
                {
                    Embed = imagePartId,
                    CompressionState = OXML.Drawing.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                };
                _bf.Append(_b);

                OXML.Drawing.Stretch _str = new OXML.Drawing.Stretch();
                OXML.Drawing.FillRectangle _fr = new OXML.Drawing.FillRectangle();
                _str.Append(_fr);
                _bf.Append(_str);

                OXML.Drawing.Pictures.ShapeProperties _shp = new OXML.Drawing.Pictures.ShapeProperties();
                OXML.Drawing.Transform2D _t2d = new OXML.Drawing.Transform2D();
                OXML.Drawing.Offset _os = new OXML.Drawing.Offset()
                {
                    X = 0L,
                    Y = 0L
                };
                OXML.Drawing.Extents _ex = new OXML.Drawing.Extents()
                {
                    Cx = 989965L,
                    Cy = 791845L
                };

                _t2d.Append(_os);
                _t2d.Append(_ex);

                OXML.Drawing.PresetGeometry _preGeo = new OXML.Drawing.PresetGeometry()
                {
                    Preset = OXML.Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle
                };
                OXML.Drawing.AdjustValueList _adl = new OXML.Drawing.AdjustValueList();
                _preGeo.Append(_adl);

                _shp.Append(_t2d);
                _shp.Append(_preGeo);

                _pic.Append(_nvpp);
                _pic.Append(_bf);
                _pic.Append(_shp);

                _gd.Append(_pic);
                _g.Append(_gd);

                _anchor.Append(_spos);
                _anchor.Append(_hp);
                _anchor.Append(_vp);
                _anchor.Append(_e);
                _anchor.Append(_ee);
                _anchor.Append(_wp);
                _anchor.Append(_dp);
                _anchor.Append(_g);

                _drawing.Append(_anchor);

                return _drawing;
            }
```

I appended the returned `Drawing` object in `Paragraph` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and it worked for me.

```
private static Drawing DrawingManager(string relationshipId, string name, Int64Value cxVal, Int64Value cyVal, string impPosition)  
    {
        string haPosition = impPosition;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(haPosition))
        {
            haPosition = "left";
        }
        // Define the reference of the image.
        DW.Anchor anchor = new DW.Anchor();
        anchor.Append(new DW.SimplePosition() { X = 0L, Y = 0L });
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.HorizontalPosition(
                new DW.HorizontalAlignment(haPosition)
            )
            {
                RelativeFrom =
                  DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Margin
            }
        );
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.VerticalPosition(
                new DW.PositionOffset("0")
            )
            {
                RelativeFrom =
                DW.VerticalRelativePositionValues.Paragraph
            }
        );
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.Extent()
            {
                Cx = cxVal,
                Cy = cyVal
            }
        );
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
                LeftEdge = 0L,
                TopEdge = 0L,
                RightEdge = 0L,
                BottomEdge = 0L
            }
        );
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(impPosition))
        {
            anchor.Append(new DW.WrapTopBottom());
        }
        else
        {
            anchor.Append(new DW.WrapNone());
        }
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.DocProperties()
            {
                Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                Name = name
            }
        );
        anchor.Append(
            new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                  new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true })
        );
        anchor.Append(
            new A.Graphic(
                  new A.GraphicData(
                    new PIC.Picture(
    
                      new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                        new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                        {
                            Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                            Name = name + ".jpg"
                        },
                        new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
    
                        new PIC.BlipFill(
                            new A.Blip(
                                new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                    new A.BlipExtension()
                                    {
                                        Uri =
                                        "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                    })
                            )
                            {
                                Embed = relationshipId,
                                CompressionState =
                                A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                            },
                            new A.Stretch(
                                new A.FillRectangle())),
    
                      new PIC.ShapeProperties(
    
                        new A.Transform2D(
                          new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
    
                          new A.Extents()
                          {
                              Cx = cxVal,
                              Cy = cyVal
                          }),
    
                        new A.PresetGeometry(
                          new A.AdjustValueList()
                        ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }
                      )
                    )
              ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
        );
    
        anchor.DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U;
        anchor.DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U;
        anchor.DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)114300U;
        anchor.DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)114300U;
        anchor.SimplePos = false;
        anchor.RelativeHeight = (UInt32Value)251658240U;
        anchor.BehindDoc = true;
        anchor.Locked = false;
        anchor.LayoutInCell = true;
        anchor.AllowOverlap = true;
    
        Drawing element = new Drawing();
        element.Append(anchor);
    
        return element;
    }
```